# Haskell AS binding on irrefutable pattern

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use both irrefutable pattern and AS bindings into a function that evaluate a reverse polish notation expression.

Here is my code:

```
resolveRPN :: String -> [Integer]
resolveRPN = foldl helper [] . words 
    where 
        helper ~stack@(x1:x2:xs) el 
            | el == "+" = (x2 + x1) : xs
            | el == "-" = (x2 - x1) : xs
            | el == "*" = (x2 * x1) : xs
            | el == "/" = (x2 `div` x1) : xs
            | otherwise = (read el) : stack
```

Basically the irrefutable will fail if you give a list with less than 2 elements but this should be only used for "+-*/".
If the function is applied to "10 10" it should just use the "otherwise" and use the AS binding "stack" and should not try to break it into constructos, but is seems it doesn't work like that.

If for instance I fold with helper and use [0,0] as accumulator, everithing works fine even if there is no need of this values.

Can someone explain why this code still raise "irrefutable pattern" excepton ? Or how Haskell evaluate this ?

Here is the simplified code :

```
notWorking :: [Int]
notWorking = helper [] "10" 
        where 
            helper ~stack@(x1:x2:xs) el = (read el) : stack  

working:: [Int]
working = helper [] "10" 
    where 
        helper ~stack el = (read el) : stack
```

Comment: Your architecture is bad and you should feel bad. Decouple parsing from evaluation.

Comment: @rightfold I have a workaround for this using a second where with `(x1:x2:xs) = stack` but i'm not iterested in "How can i solve this problem" but "How Haskell works and why this is not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thumb rule is:

- an irrefutable/lazy pattern `~p` matches everything
- if a variable `x` in `p` is demanded, consider all the constructors in the syntactic tree of `p` reachable from `x` except for moving *downwards* across a `~`: the value being matched will be evaluated to match these constructors
- if the match above fails, raise an exception

Example:

```
case value of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> ...
```

- if we do not demand anything, then `value` will not be evaluated
- if we demand `x` or `y` or `ys`, then `value` will be evaluated as much as needed to match `y:ys` (and the triple)
- if we demand `z` or `w` or `ws`, then `value` will be evaluated as much as needed to match `y:ys` and `w:ws` (and the triple and the pair)

Tests:

```
> case undefined of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> "hello"
"hello"
> case (3,undefined,(4,[1])) of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> x
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
> case (3,[],(4,[1])) of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> x
*** Exception: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (x, y : ys, ~(z, w : ws))
> case (3,[0],(4,undefined)) of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> x
3
> case (3,[0],(4,[])) of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> x
3
> case (3,[],(4,[1])) of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> z
*** Exception: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (x, y : ys, ~(z, w : ws))
> case (3,[0],(4,[])) of ~(x,y:ys,~(z,w:ws)) -> z
*** Exception: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (z, w : ws)
```

In my opinion, the semantic could be nicer if every subpattern under a `~` behaved as if it had `~` above it. E.g. if `~(x,y:ys)` were equivalent to `~(x,~(y:ys))`. The current semantics does allow for more flexibility, though.

---

The rule holds even in the presence of "as" patterns. For instance, in

```
case value of a@ ~(x,y:ys,~b@(z,c@(w:ws))) -> ...
```

demanding `a` will not evaluate the `value` but demanding any other variable
will cause `value` to be evaluated so to match the triple.
Further, demanding any of `x,y,ys` will also cause the evaluation to match
the list constructor in `y:ys`. Instead, matching `b` or any of `z,c,w,ws` will cause `value` to be evaluated further, so to match the pair `(z,c@(w:ws))` as well as the list `w:ws`, which are under the second `~`.

```
--Here is an example with "as" pattern outside that will succeed
> case (1,[],(2,[3])) of a@ ~(x,y:ys,~b@(z,c@(w:ws))) -> a
(1,[],(2,[3]))

--This will fail because the triple as well as y:ys will be evaluated along a
> case (1,[],(2,[3])) of ~a@(x,y:ys,~b@(z,c@(w:ws))) -> a
*** Exception: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern a@(x, y : ys, ~b@(z, c@(w : ws)))
```

---

In your code you can simply put the "as" binding outside the `~` like this:

```
helper stack@ ~(x1:x2:xs) el 
    | el == "+" = (x2 + x1) : xs
    | el == "-" = (x2 - x1) : xs
    | el == "*" = (x2 * x1) : xs
    | el == "/" = (x2 `div` x1) : xs
    | otherwise = (read el) : stack
```

and will work fine for any valid RPN input.

Comment: My problem was not in understanding `thumb` but in using it in combination with as binding. I thought in this expression  `~stack @ (x1:x2:xs)` the thumb is applied just for `(x1:x2:xs)` not on `stack` as well. I was beginning to suspect that as binding is just syntactic sugar for `(x1:x2:xs)` and that's the reason for failure.

Comment: Can you please adapt your answer with `as pattern` so i can accept your answer ?

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru I added an example with as-patterns.

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru By the way, `~` is not called "thumb". I referred to my quick rule as a "thumb rule" in the usual English meaning of "quick, possibly not covering 100% of cases, but useful rule" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb

Answer (score 3):

The irrefutable pattern is appling for `stack@(x1:x2:xs)` not on each one so when you try to extract `stack` this will atuomatically evaluate `(x1:x2:xs)`.

This problem can be FIXED using irrefutable only for pattern matching but not on as binding defining `hepler` like this:

```
helper stack@ ~(x1:x2:xs) el 
        | el == "+" = (x2 + x1) : xs
        | el == "-" = (x2 - x1) : xs
        | el == "*" = (x2 * x1) : xs
        | el == "/" = (x2 `div` x1) : xs
        | otherwise = (read el) : stack
```

and this will never fails on valid expressions.

Comment: I did a quick test in GHCi, and I had to use another pair of parentheses: `helper stack@(~(x1:x2:xs)) el ...`.

Comment: You are right: I was using `stack@~(...` without the space in between.

Answer (score 0):

The irrefutable pattern fails when we try to print the resulting list:

```
head $ resolveRPN "2 4 +" -- 6, no error
resolveRPN "2 4 +" -- error
```

In the above example, we don't have a proper `[]` at the end of the resulting list. Instead, we have an irrefutable `(:)` pattern, which throws an error. In other words, `~(x:xs)` can't function as an empty list, even if we don't actually try to access head or the tail in the pattern.

Comment: When using head $ resolveRPN "2 4 +" is working because of haskell lazyness on otherwise branch: it only evaluate (read el) and don't care at all about stack because this value is not required for printing the result

Comment: That's true. Is there perhaps somethings that's not clear to you in the answer?

Comment: if u apply "2 4 +" to that function: for first 2 elements should only use stack and should not try to split it into elements (because of AS binding), at the moment "+" will be evaluated there are already 2 elements in the acc: 2 and 4. The problem is that, it is fails even for "2 2" because of the pattern but this shouldn't because i only use AT binding so it shouldn't care about if stack can be slipted or not

Comment: @GabrielCiubotaru it fails for "2 2" because the one-element list can't be matched. Your pattern matches only on lists with at least two elements. You can make the inner pattern irrefutable too, like `~stack@(x1: ~(x2:xs))`, and this way `take 2 $ resolveRPN "2 2"` works fine.

Comment: The principle is the same: if you try to evaluate non-matching patterns, you get an error. Your code always returns a list with a non-matching pattern in the back.

Comment: I just add a simplified version of my problem at the end of the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77310/discussion-between-gabriel-ciubotaru-and-andras-kovacs).